# Equivalent of \nsubseteq without the equality

Tags: math-mode

There are two different symbols to represent that a set is a subset of another set: `\subset` and `\subseteq`. Now, to symbolize that a set is **not** a subset, one could use `\nsubseteq`, but is there also equivalent sign for `\subset`, e.g. sth like `\nsubset`? The last command doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: `\not\subset` ?

Comment: `lmathabx` has this symbol, and it is easy to use only the symbol, without changing your default math font.

Comment: Did the provided answer solve the question?

Comment: David Carlisle's answer \not\subset works on my machine

Answer (score 3):

Looking this package named [centernot](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/centernot.pdf) there is written:

> **§1.** If a negated relational symbol is not available, `\not` can be used to create the negated variant of the relational symbol. The disadvantage of `\not` is that it is
> put at a fixed location regardless of the width of the relational symbol. Therefore `\centernot` takes an argument and measures its width to achieve a better
> placement of the symbol `\not`.

Hence:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{centernot}

\begin{document}
$A \centernot\subset B$
\end{document}
```

[image]

**PS**: *If you want you can create a specific macro*.